# Find and match nearest row value based on criterion

Tags: r, pattern-matching, match

Looking for help to write a tricky piece of R code.

I have a data frame of the following structure:

```
#make fake data
category<-c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b")
cat.id<-rep(1:5, 2)
time <- seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("10/24/16 21:05", format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M", tz="America/Chicago"), by="5 min", length.out=10)
x<-c(0.2, 3, 4, 0.5, 1.4, 3, 1.9, 2.2, 4, 1.2)

data<-data.frame(category, cat.id, time, x)

>data
   category cat.id                time   x
1         a      1 2016-10-24 21:05:00 0.2
2         a      2 2016-10-24 21:10:00 3.0
3         a      3 2016-10-24 21:15:00 4.0
4         a      4 2016-10-24 21:20:00 0.5
5         a      5 2016-10-24 21:25:00 1.4
6         b      1 2016-10-24 21:30:00 3.0
7         b      2 2016-10-24 21:35:00 1.9
8         b      3 2016-10-24 21:40:00 2.2
9         b      4 2016-10-24 21:45:00 4.0
10        b      5 2016-10-24 21:50:00 1.2
```

For each subset of "category" (e.g., "a" or "b"), I need to shift "cat.id" such that: 
    -if "x" is < 2, then "cat.id" is matched (or shifted) to the closest preceding value of "cat.id" where x is >= 2. 
    -the shifted "cat.id" value is stored in column "cat.idshifted"
    -For values of "cat.id" == 1, there is no shift because there is no preceding value for that subset of "category"

This would produce a data frame like:

```
data$cat.idshifted<-c(1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 4, 4)
>data
   category cat.id                time   x cat.idshifted
1         a      1 2016-10-24 21:05:00 0.2             1
2         a      2 2016-10-24 21:10:00 3.0             2
3         a      3 2016-10-24 21:15:00 4.0             3
4         a      4 2016-10-24 21:20:00 0.5             3
5         a      5 2016-10-24 21:25:00 1.4             3
6         b      1 2016-10-24 21:30:00 3.0             1
7         b      2 2016-10-24 21:35:00 1.9             1
8         b      3 2016-10-24 21:40:00 2.2             3
9         b      4 2016-10-24 21:45:00 4.0             4
10        b      5 2016-10-24 21:50:00 1.2             4
```

The basic idea is that "cat.id" represents the number of collected data files for "category". Sometimes data files that actually belong to a single event are split into multiple files because of hardware issues. So 1 data event may actually be collected in 3 files. You can figure out which files go together by looking at "x". If the value of x<2, then the files go together. And since 1 file can be split into many, a sequence of x < 2 would represent multiple files that belong together.

So what I want to do, is index/find each time that x < 2, and adjust the "cat.id" or file id to the correct value, which happens to be when the closest in time previous file with x >= 2 was collected.

I'm thinking a function that indexes the closest (in time) >=2 value of "x" might be appropriate. Then the indexed value would return the "cat.id" value to "cat.idshifted".

I'm familiar with which.max, etc. to index values, however I don't know how to index values by saying "give me the thing that is the closest preceding value".

I didn't include here for simplicity, but x is actually the amount of time between each files collection. E.g., it's a difftime object. Perhaps a while loop could work? Where: 
-While there are x < 2 values
-Shift cat.id value back 1 (e.g, cat.id-1)
-Recompute difftime
-Check if there are still values of x<2, repeat if until not true.

Any thoughts on this tricky bit of code?

Comment: good catch and keen eyes! edited to correct.

Comment: Can't answer the question, but for "give me the thing that is the closest preceding value", this'll work:
`y<-5.4 x<-rnorm(10,6,1) x[x<=y][which.min(abs(x[x<=y] - y))]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
# Create 'temp' column to indicate whether record belongs to previous file (0) or not (cat.id)
data$temp = ifelse(data$x < 2, 0, data$cat.id)
data$temp[data$cat.id==1] = 1

# Take the cumulative max of 'temp' by category.
data$cat.idshifted = unlist(by(data, data$category, function(da) cummax(da$temp)))

> data
#    category cat.id                time   x temp cat.idshifted
# 1         a      1 2016-10-24 21:05:00 0.2    1             1
# 2         a      2 2016-10-24 21:10:00 3.0    2             2
# 3         a      3 2016-10-24 21:15:00 4.0    3             3
# 4         a      4 2016-10-24 21:20:00 0.5    0             3
# 5         a      5 2016-10-24 21:25:00 1.4    0             3
# 6         b      1 2016-10-24 21:30:00 3.0    1             1
# 7         b      2 2016-10-24 21:35:00 1.9    0             1
# 8         b      3 2016-10-24 21:40:00 2.2    3             3
# 9         b      4 2016-10-24 21:45:00 4.0    4             4
# 10        b      5 2016-10-24 21:50:00 1.2    0             4
```

Comment: Thank you! This works also and runs much more quickly (about 7 sec faster) than the above. I'm having a bit of trouble understanding exactly how the last line of code work. I understand what you're doing up to the final line of code. Could you expand a bit? Apologies, I don't typically use those functions.

Comment: @griffmer `by` splits the data into chunks by unique values of `da$category`, and applies the function I defined, which is to take the cumulative max of `temp`, to each chunk. It returns a list so you need to `unlist` to get a vector

Answer (score 0):

```
data$cat.idshifted <- NA

for(c in data$category){
  for(i in which(data$category==c)){
    if(data$cat.id[i]==1){
      data$cat.idshifted[i] <- data$cat.id[i]      
    } else if(data$x[i]<=2){
        data$cat.idshifted[i] <- max( data$cat.id[data$x > 2 & data$category==c & data$cat.id < data$cat.id[i]])
      } else if(data$x[i]>2){
        data$cat.idshifted[i] <- data$cat.id[i]   
      }
    }
}

data
```

> ```
>    category cat.id                time   x cat.idshifted
> 1         a      1 2016-10-24 21:05:00 0.2             1
> 2         a      2 2016-10-24 21:10:00 3.0             2
> 3         a      3 2016-10-24 21:15:00 4.0             3
> 4         a      4 2016-10-24 21:20:00 0.5             3
> 5         a      5 2016-10-24 21:25:00 1.4             3
> 6         b      1 2016-10-24 21:30:00 3.0             1
> 7         b      2 2016-10-24 21:35:00 1.9             1
> 8         b      3 2016-10-24 21:40:00 2.2             3
> 9         b      4 2016-10-24 21:45:00 4.0             4
> 10        b      5 2016-10-24 21:50:00 1.2             4
> ```

If you wanted to make this a bit shorter you could combine by first `if` and my second `else if` into one `if` statement with the `|` operator, but this works as is.

The way the statement:

`max( data$cat.id[data$x > 2 & data$category==c & data$cat.id < data$cat.id[i]])`

works is that is says the following:

- I want my replacement `cat.id` to correspond to one where the value of `x` is > 2, hence the `data$x > 2` part
- I only want to look within the same category for a replacement (`data$category==c`)
- I want the replacement to precede the target (`data$cat.id < data$cat.id[i]`)
- I want the nearest row fitting the above criteria (this is why you use `max()` )

Comment: This is working fantastically. Sorry for the slow response, took me a moment to translate into my own code.